# Creating visualforce custom buttons depending on data retrieved

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am very new in salesforce and i am trying to create a custom buttons depending on how many data i retrieve from the object field. For Example in my apex controller function **get_bttns()** will retrieve {edit_record,delete_record} , The Visualforce page will display the following buttons (edit_record button and delete_record button).

HERE IS MY SAMPLE CODE

APEX CONTROLLER

```
public class Example_CTRL {

    public static List<Button_List__c> bttns()
    {
        return [Select Id,actions__c FROM Button_List__c];
    }

}
```

VISUALFORCE

```
<apex:page controller="Example_CTRL">

    <apex:form>
    dont know what to do here
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you can use apex:repeat and generate buttons

```
<apex:page standardController="Example_CTRL">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
         <apex:repeat value="{!Button_List}" var="btn">
          <apex:commandbutton id="{!btn.id}" value="{!btn.value}" action="{!btn.action__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```